# str.split() in the for-loop instantiation, does it cause slower execution?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization

I'm a sucker for reducing code to its bare minimum and love keeping it short and slim, but occasionally I get into the dilemma of whether I'm doing more harm than good. Below is an example of a situation I frequently encounter and where I start pondering if I am minifying at the expense of speed.

```
str = "my name is john"

##Alternative 1
for el in str.split(" "):
    print(el)

##Alternative 2
splittedStr = str.split(" ")

for el in splittedStr:
    print(el)
```

What is faster? I'd assume it's the second one because we don't split the string after every iteration (not even sure we do that)?

Answer (score 2):

`str.split(" ")` does the exact same thing in both cases. It creates an anonymous list of the split strings. In the second case you have the minor overhead of assigning it to a variable and then fetching the value of the variable. Its wasted time if you don't need to keep the object for other reasons. But this is a trivial amount of time compared to other object referencing taking place in the same loop. Alternative 2 also leaves the data in memory which is another small performance issue.

The real reason Alternative 1 is better than 2, IMHO, is that it doesn't leave the hint that `splittedStr` is going to be needed later.

Answer (score -1):

Look my friend, if you want to actually reduce the amount of time in the code in general,loop on a tuple instead of list but assigning the result in a variable then using the variable is not the best approach is you just reserved a memory location just to store the value but sometimes you can do that just for the sake of having a clean code like if you have more than one operation in one line like

```
min(str.split(mylist)[3:10])
```

In this case, it is better to have a variable called min_value for example just to make things cleaner.

returning back to the performance issue, you could actually notice the difference in performance if you loop through a list or a tuple like

This is looping through a tuple

```
for i in (1,2,3):
   print(i)
```

& This is looping through a list

```
 for i in [1,2,3]:
        print(i)
```

you will find that using tuple will be faster !